# Dash Bootstrap Components: Create Table with links from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

**EDIT: Please don't invest time into an answer - I found the solution myself, but instead of deleting it I want to keep it for others in case they have the same problem. I cannot close it however, but no need to provide additional answers, thanks!**

Title already says it all - I want to create a [dbc table](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/table/) from a pandas Dataframe. However, it looks like the columns are not being parsed, neither with HTML nor with markdown syntax:

```
p = {}  
p["LinkColumn"] = f'<a href="{my_link}">Link</a>' # Does not work
p["LinkColumn"] = f'[link]({my_link})'            # Does not work either...

# Code is simplified, but the idea is to create pd.DataFrame then dbc Table:
dbc.Table.from_dataframe(pd.DataFrame(p))
```

Both variants simply print everything in plain text, meaning the link is displayed as text instead of linking to the page I want. Is there another way to do it? Maybe some option like `parse_html=True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I realized that the Dash html components are being parsed, including the [link component](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/a):

```
p["LinkColumn"] = html.A("Link", href=my_link)
```